# What was the early churches view on head-covering for women?

Tags: church-history, early-church, 1-corinthians

A somewhat controversial topic, but there are certain verses in the Bible such as 1 Corinthians 11, which command women to wear head-coverings in church, but was the early church view of women wearing head-coverings in general, did they or did they not support it?

Comment: The early Church is the Church that formed during the time of Jesus and thereafter. Jesus went first to the Jews and then the non-Jews. Jewish women cover their heads. And this continued in the early Church. It is the later Church that became watered down that let women not cover their heads, and this goes against the scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

Holy Bible

> “Every man praying or prophesying, having his head covered, dishonors
> his head. But every woman who prays or prophesies with her head
> uncovered dishonors her head, for that is one and the same as if her
> head were shaved” (1 Cor. 11:4,5)

The historical record reveals that the early churches all understood Paul to be talking about a cloth head covering, not long hair. The only thing that wasn’t clear to some of the early Christians was whether or not Paul’s instructions apply to all females or only to married women. The reason is that the Greek word gyne, used by Paul, can mean “a female” or it can mean “a married woman.”

Around the year 200, at Carthage, North Africa, Tertullian wrote a tract entitled, “The Veiling of Virgins.” Tertullian makes the argument that the passage applies to all females of age—not just to married women. Of course, Tertullian’s personal view is of little concern to us. But what is so valuable about this work of his is that he discusses the practices of different churches in various parts of the world. Here are some key excerpts from his work:

> I also admonish you second group of women, who are married, not to
> outgrow the discipline of the veil. Not even for a moment of an hour.
> Because you can’t avoid wearing a veil, you should not find some other
> way to nullify it. That is, by going about neither covered nor bare.
> For some women do not veil their heads, but rather bind them up with
> turbans and woollen bands. It’s true that they are protected in front.
> But where the head properly lies, they are bare.
>
> Others cover only the area of the brain with small linen coifs that do
> not even quite reach the ears…. They should know that the entire head
> constitutes the woman. Its limits and boundaries reach as far as the
> place where the robe begins. The region of the veil is co-extensive
> with the space covered by the hair when it is unbound. In this way,
> the neck too is encircled.
>
> The pagan women of Arabia will be your judges. For they cover not only
> the head, but the face also. . . . But how severe a chastisement will
> they likewise deserve, who remain uncovered even during the recital of
> the Psalms and at any mention of the name of God? For even when they
> are about to spend time in prayer itself, they only place a fringe,
> tuft [of cloth], or any thread whatever on the crown of their heads.
> And they think that they are covered!
>
> Earlier in his tract, Tertullian testified that the churches that were
> founded by the apostles did insist that both their married women and
> their virgins be veiled:
>
> Throughout Greece, and certain of its barbaric provinces, the majority
> of churches keep their virgins covered. In fact, this practice is
> followed in certain places beneath this African sky. So let no one
> ascribe this custom merely to the Gentile customs of the Greeks and
> barbarians.
>
> Moreover, I will put forth as models those churches that were founded
> by either apostles or apostolic men. . . . The Corinthians themselves
> understood him to speak in this manner. For to this very day the
> Corinthians veil their virgins. What the apostles taught, the
> disciples of the apostles confirmed. [Tertullian, The Veiling of
> Virgins The Ante-Nicene Fathers Vol. 4 pp. 27-29,33]

Clement of Alexandria, Bishop writing from Egypt around the year 190, counseled:

> “Let the woman observe this, further. Let her be entirely covered
> unless she happens to be at home. For that style of dress is grave,
> and protects from being gazed at. And she will never fall, who puts
> before her eyes modesty, and her shawl; nor will she invite another to
> fall into sin by uncovering her face. For this is the wish of the
> Word, since it is becoming for her to pray veiled.” [Clement, The
> Instructor 3.12]

Hippolytus, a leader in the church at Rome around the year 200, compiled a record of the various customs and practices in that church from the generations that preceded him. His Apostolic Tradition contains this statement:

> And let all the women have their heads covered with an opaque cloth,
> not with a veil of thin linen, for this is not a true covering.
> [Hippolytus Apostolic Tradition]

In summary, the early Christians practiced exactly what 1 Cor. 11 says: Men prayed with their heads uncovered. Women prayed with their heads covered.

Via - [earlychurch.com](https://earlychurch.com/the-head-covering-or-prayer-veil/)